# Loading txt.file into matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I hope someone can help me with this problem:

I need to load a txt.file into matlab. The txt.file look something like this:

```
1 80  1 . 32 
1.374 1 0 . 0
```

It contains 38 variables and 11,674 observations (I know this because I have successfully loaded the data into STATA). '.' are missing values. I use the code below:

```
data = textread('data.txt','','delimiter','.','emptyvalue',NaN);
```

This does not give me any errors. However, the resulting data only contains 11674 rows and 12 columns. When comparing the data in matlab with the text-file it appears that matlab only reads the the first quarter of the textfile.

I have also tried to load the DATA into STATA, export it to excel and then use:

```
data = xlsread('data.xls','Sheet1');
```

This does not work either because I do not have windows. Matlab reports the error:

```
Warning: Could not start Excel server for import, 'basic' mode will be used.
Error using xlsread (line 232)
XLSREAD unable to read sheet Sheet1.
Error reading record for cells starting at column 0.  Try saving as Excel 98.
```

If you need additional information please let me know.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does the `.` ever stand for a decimal point, or is it only ever a "no data" marker. It's a very poor choice of character… Either way you should not treat it as a delimiter. In your second line you have the number `1.374`. Is that meant to be a single number, or `1, missing, 374`?

Comment: Not every . is a missin value. 1.374 is for instance a number. Not 1, missing, 374. However, txt2mat solved it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

txt2mat [1] should solve your problem. If you use the 'block'-reading mode, it is also much faster than the plain textread method.

You may fill unrecognized (e.g. the empty cells) by NaN and detect these subsequently.

Alternatively you may replace the dots already during file import:

```
DATA = txt2mat(filename, 'ReplaceChar', '. ');
```

[1] http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18430-txt2mat

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken the `.` is not a delimiter. 
What you can do to get rid of `.` in your file (which is causing the problem) is to replace it with `NaN` either in the first place, or if you can't, do it after:

```
str = fileread('data.txt');
data_str = strrep(str, ' . ', ' NaN ');
```

Note the two empty spaces before and after `.` and `NaN`.

Then you can use `textread` or any other standard data reading function.

Hope it helps.