# Ignoring certain columns when importing data files into Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to import a 100000 x 101 data file to Matlab using the load function however I do not require the first column in the data file. So my question is, is there any other way to ignore or remove this column than just removing the column manually. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of data? Which function is used to import?

Comment: The data is all numerical, and each column is separated by spaces. I just use the function `load myfilename.dat`. I will be using the data to plot a heat graph using HeatMap function but I think that is irrelevant to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the function `load`, it is the only way

```
load myfilename.dat; myfilename = myfilename(:,2:101);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case (text based file) any method must internally parse the full file to find all delimiters. It might be possible with some functions to ignore a column, but is not worth the effort because the speed does not increase.

With Binary files (e.g. mat) you can be skip columns while reading. Here the position of the data is known.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the size of your file, Matlab's `load` may not be the most efficient way to import the data. Consider my posting at [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275069/loading-txt-file-into-matlab/20275252#20275252) for instance. The function `txt2mat` will enable you to read the data very fast using the command

```
%read data
DATA = txt2mat(filename, 'ReplaceChar', '. ');
%discard the first column
DATA = DATA[:,2:end]
```

Of course, you have read unnecessary data, but the speed of `txt2mat` should overcome this overhead.

txt2mat can be found at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18430-txt2mat